# await each element in loop NodeJS to execute findOneAndDelete Method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, mongoose-schema, node-async

I want to execute a schema statistics as post findOneAndDelete middleware in mongoose. My code is calling the schema when I am looping over but it just calculate for only one document deletion.

I have searched over many question and answer but didn't work yet,

```
exports.deleteAllAssociatedAns = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const allAssocAnswers = await Answer.find({
    answerOfQuesId: req.params.quesId,
  });
  if (!allAssocAnswers || allAssocAnswers.length === 0) {
    next();
  }

  await Promise.all(
    Array.from(allAssocAnswers).map(async (el) => {
      const deletedAnswer = await Answer.findOneAndDelete({
        _id: el._id,
      });
      if (!deletedAnswer) {
        return next(new AppError('Something Went Wrong, Try Again!', 404));
      }
    })
  );

 //Next Middleware
});
```

FindOneAndDelete then call a schema statistics,

```
answerSchema.statics.calcUserAnswerStatistics = async function (
  userId,
  status
) {
  const stats = await this.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { answerAuthor: userId },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$answerAuthor',
        nAnswers: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ]);
  if (stats.length > 0) {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);
    const userPoints = user.earnedPoints;
    const qnaCount = user.totalQnaCount;
    console.log(userPoints); **//This is consoling 4 Times If there is 4 Result but the below calculation is just calculating one time**

    if (status === 'new') {
      user.earnedPoints = userPoints + 5;
      user.totalQnaCount = qnaCount + 1;
      user.givenAnswersCount = stats[0].nAnswers;
    } else {
      user.earnedPoints = userPoints - 5; **//Just Decrease Ones**
      user.totalQnaCount = qnaCount - 1; **//Just Decrease Ones**
      user.givenAnswersCount = stats[0].nAnswers;
    }

    await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
  } else {
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
      givenAnswersCount: 0,
    });
  }
};

answerSchema.post(/^findOneAndDe/, async function () {
  const ansOfQues = await Question.findById(this.r.answerOfQuesId);
  ansOfQues.answerCount -= 1; **//If there is Four Time Calls Count Should Decrease 4 in total but problem is it just decreasing one**
  await ansOfQues.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });

  await this.r.constructor.calcUserAnswerStatistics(
    this.r.answerAuthor,
    'deleted'
  ); **//This method is called 4 times but calculate only ones**
});
```

Comment: If you are deleting multiple answers from the same question at the same time, you probably just have a race condition.

Comment: `return next(new AppError(…))` should be `throw new AppError(…)`, otherwise you'd call `next` multiple times in the case of multiple errors in the concurrent loop.

Comment: @Bergi no error is thrown after using throw new AppError(). Also there is no error in this loop, The program is running fine for one answer deletion, But why not in multiple answer? What should be the way to make it working?

Comment: Yes i am deleting multiple answers from the same question, And I want that when a question will be deleted then all the associated answer will be deleted but at the same time this programme will look over those delete answer authors and decrease their earned points as their answer is going to delete. How may I achieve this is their any other solution or could you please fix this existing one as answer I wanna mark that as answer.

Comment: @Bergi searched a lot, to fix race condition, but didn't get appropriate answer to solve this issue, Could you please check it out how I use lock in this specific case?

Comment: It's really not clear how `Answer.findOneAndDelete` does call the `answerSchema.post(/^findOneAndDe/, …)` handler (which looks more like an endpoint of a separate service?). Are you using some framework there?

Comment: No, I don't know how to use locks with mongodb. The simplest solution would probably to do a sequential iteration in `deleteAllAssociatedAns` instead

Comment: When I will Delete something via findOneAndDelete() method it will then call answerSchema.post() middlewire, after deleting documents via this method, it will not called when i delete something via findByIdAndDelete() method on this schema, because that post middlewre is specific for the method started with /^findOneAndDe/ means findOneAndDelete(). I am just using express with nodejs.

Comment: @Bergi my be sequential iteration is the way left to do so. You may submit all this as answer, if you get something new with it. Thanks!